# NSColorPanel blocking mouse up events

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscolorpanel

I am using a NSColorWell which is set to continuously update. I need to know when the user is done editing the control (mouse up) from the color picker in the color panel.

I installed an event monitor and am successfully receiving mouse down and mouse moved messages, however NSColorPanel appears to block mouse up.

The bottom line is that I want to add the final selected color to my undo stack without all the intermediate colors generated while the user is choosing their selection.

Is there a way of creating a custom NSColorPanel and replacing the shared panel with the thought of overriding its mouseUp and sending a message?

In my research this issue has been broached on a few occasions, however I have not read a successful resolution.

Regards,
- George Lawrence Storm, Keencoyote Invention Services

Answer (score 5):

I discovered that if we observe `color` keypath of `NSColorPanel` we get called one extra time on mouse up events. This allows us to ignore action messages from `NSColorWell` when the left mouse button is down and to get the final color from keypath observer.

In this application delegate example code `colorChanged:` is a `NSColorWell` action method.

```
void* const ColorPanelColorContext = (void*)1001;

@interface AppDelegate()

@property (weak) NSColorWell *updatingColorWell;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSColorPanel *colorPanel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
    [colorPanel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"color" 
                    options:0 context:ColorPanelColorContext];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object 
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == ColorPanelColorContext) {
        if (![self isLeftMouseButtonDown]) {
            if (self.updatingColorWell) {
                NSColorWell *colorWell = self.updatingColorWell;
                [colorWell sendAction:[colorWell action] to:[colorWell target]];
            }
            self.updatingColorWell = nil;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)colorChanged:(id)sender {
    if ([self isLeftMouseButtonDown]) {
        self.updatingColorWell = sender;
    } else {
        NSColorWell *colorWell = sender;
        [self updateFinalColor:[colorWell color]];
        self.updatingColorWell = nil;
    }
}

- (void)updateFinalColor:(NSColor*)color {
    // Do something with the final color...
}

- (BOOL)isLeftMouseButtonDown {
    return ([NSEvent pressedMouseButtons] & 1) == 1;
}

@end
```

Comment: You also simply change NSColorPanel's `continous` property to `NO`. Then the `setAction:` message only fires on mouse up.

Answer (score 2):

In the Interface Builder, select your color well, and then uncheck the Continuous checkbox in the Attributes Inspector. Additionally, add the following line of code somewhere appropriate like in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method or `awakeFromNib` method:

```
[[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setContinuous:NO];
```

In other words, both the shared color panel and your color well need to have continuous set to `NO` in order for this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do what you want is to use `NSUndoManager`'s [`-begin/endUndoGrouping`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). So you'd do something like this

```
[undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
// ... whatever code you need to show the color picker
// ...then when the color has been chosen
[undoManager endUndoGrouping];
```

The purpose of undo groups is exactly what you're trying to accomplish - to make all changes into a single undo.

Comment: I apparently was not clear in my question. The issue is that I never receive an event that indicates that I am done editing the color well, therefore I have no way of knowing when to end undo. Currently I have sub classed NSColorWell and end undo grouping when it resigns responder. This allows for undo, however it is not consistent with other drawing behaviors. Normally when drawing a graphic element using the mouse the undo is committed on mouse up. I would like to have similar behavior from the color well, so that multiple "mouse up" commits are recorded without having to leave the well.